# Vuetify icons are shown on carousel but not on v-icon

Tags: vue.js, vuetify.js

So i am trying to use v-icon with Material Design Icons (JS SVG) found here in the official [documentation](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/customization/icons) because it is what the carousel ui component uses but the icons are simply not showing up.

I've installed the library and the carousel can use it just fine but whenever i try to use it in v-icon it doesn't show up, with or without "mdi-" prefix.

Here is a very simple example of the tag usage

```
<v-icon>mdi-account-box</v-icon>
```

here is my Vuetify.js config file

```
import Vue from 'vue';
import Vuetify from 'vuetify/lib';

Vue.use(Vuetify);

export default new Vuetify({
  theme: {
      options: {
        customProperties: true,
      },
    themes: {
      light: {
        primary: '#ee44aa',
        secondary: '#424242',
        accent: '#82B1FF',
        error: '#FF5252',
        info: '#2196F3',
        success: '#4CAF50',
        warning: '#FFC107'
      },
    },
  },
  icons: {
    iconfont: 'mdiSvg',
  },
});
```

Any icon i try using from [here](https://materialdesignicons.com/) doesn't show up.
No errors are shown either.

Comment: Try changing your `icons.iconfont` to "mdi".

Comment: Try just using account-box without mdi.